# How to make Z shell respect both ~/.zshrc and ~/.profile simultaneously?

Tags: command-line, zsh, macos

I use Z shell on Mac and have some settings in both .zshrc and .profile in my home directory.

I found that when I only have .profile, zsh import .profile in a new session; and when I have both .profile and .zshrc, zsh only import .zshrc while ignoring .profile.

Is there any way to make the shell respect both settings files, or import .profile in .zshrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zsh typically sources `.zprofile` rather than `.profile` at login. (It will not source `.zshrc` if the login does not go to an interactive session.) However, if you want it to source `.profile` and there's nothing specific to another shell in there (like bash-specific stuff), you can always put `source .profile` in the `.zprofile` file.

`.zshrc` is sourced when an interactive shell is invoked, whether it's a login shell or not. It doesn't source `.zprofile` again if you're not logging in, however.

I would just put everything you want always to be sourced in one of the two files, and then just have the other one source that one. For example, I keep all my aliases and environmental variables in my `.zshrc` and have the line `source $HOME/.zshrc` in my `.zprofile` so it always gets read, even in non-interactive login shells.

Just be sure not to have each of them source each other, which is tempting, as that obviously will create an infinite cycle.

You can also use a third file for the stuff you want both to do and have them both source that third file.